# Equivalent function in JavaScript/Ramda as Clojure's juxt

Tags: javascript, clojure, clojurescript, ramda.js

I need the functionality of Clojure's `juxt` function in JavaScript. Is there a native function for this? We're using the [Ramda functional JavaScript library](http://ramdajs.com/). Is there a Ramda function with the `juxt` functionality?

I know, of course, I can write this function myself. This is for educational purposes.

Comment: @zerkms - wrapping the functions in an array and the collection in an array provides the same functionality! You should put this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At some extent the [`R.ap`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#ap) looks like what you want.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways you could achieve this.

[R.converge](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#converge), which pipes the given value through each function in the provided list before using the result of each as the corresponding argument position of the function provided as the first argument to `converge` - perhaps explained better with a diagram:

```
add  = (a, b) => a + b
incr = a => a + 1
decr = a => a - a
double = converge(add, [incr, decr])

       ------       ---
5 ----| incr |- 6 -| a |
   \   ------      | d |- 10
    \-| decr |- 4 -| d |
       ------       ---
```

This can be used to emulate something similar to `juxt` as follows:

```
var argsId = R.unapply(R.identity);
var juxt = R.converge(argsId);
var addSubtract10 = juxt([R.add(10), R.subtract(10)]);
addSubtract10(5); //=> [15, 5]
```

Alternatively (though perhaps less intuitive), [R.commute](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#commute) can also be used over a list of functions. `R.commute` takes a list of some applicative type and effectively turns it inside out to become an applicative of some list, where the applicative behaviour of functions now provided by Ramda is similar to `converge`.

```
var juxt = R.commute(R.always);
var addSubtract10 = juxt([R.add(10), R.subtract(10)]);
addSubtract10(5); //=> [15, 5]
```

Comment: I love your ascii diagram. Those 2 mechanisms make sense. Though it seems `R.ap` is an even more like `juxt`.

Answer (score 0):

There is another fairly simple Ramda solution:

```
var juxt = R.useWith(R.ap, [R.identity, R.of]);
```

This was discussed in Ramda's [issue #986](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/986), but ended up being dropped when no one stepped up to champion the idea.  Feel free to bring it back up.

Comment: I realize, I think, that the difference between using `ap` and `juxt` is `ap` depends on the functions only taking in 1 argument. That's a pretty serious limitation if I understood this correctly. For that I do believe the `juxt` function should be added to Ramda.

Comment: `ap` is about compatibility with the [FantasyLand specification](https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#apply).  Any similarity with `juxt` is just a helpful coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

from version v0.19.0 Ramda added [juxt](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#juxt)